# Android Notification not showing in LG and some other devices

Tags: android, android-notification-bar, lg

I have used the following code to display a notification while starting service in the foreground.

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.statusbar_icon)
    .setContentTitle("App is running")
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
    .setPriority(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

startForeground(R.string.service_running, mBuilder.build());
```

The notification is showing in the notification bar of all devices except LG-E450 and a Samsung device. Not only this one, no notification from my application is not showing in the bar.

Comment: Are the devices producing any sort of error, or is the notification just not showing?

Comment: no errors or warnings in logcat..

Comment: There is a new system update this month for the LG-E450 (although, that may break your live wallpaper picker). Is the 'power saver' turned on? Did you pick a generic sounding package name for your app? It may be that notifications have previously been disabled for that package name. The LG-E450 seems to be a buggy phone. What is the model of the Samsung Device that has the same issue? And what are some of the names of the devices that your notifications actually worked on? Please give us at least three model names for which it worked for and tell us how many total you actually tested on.

Comment: worked on nexus 4, galaxy Ace, Sony experia and all emulators but not working on LG E450. Sorry I couldn't remember that samsung device name.

Comment: In the App settings 'Show Notifications' has beeen turned off. Thank you so much. Please post this comment as answer so that I'll accept and upvote.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states that [detail text is required](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Required) and can be set via [`NotificationCompat.Builder#setContentText(CharSequence)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setContentText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) (although my GS3 will display a notification without detail text)

Answer (score 0):

In the App settings 'Show Notifications' has beeen turned off so it should be trun on